# Algorithm that balances the number of elements in a subinterval of an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Lets say you have an array with 4 different types of elements.

```
1 1 2 3 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 1.
```

I want to find the longest subinterval that results in an equal number of each elements and the largest total number of elements.

In this case, it would be

> 1 1 2 3 1 2 2 3 3

because this results in 3 twos, 3 threes, and 3 ones.

I believe this is some sort of modified dynamic programming, or something that requires prefix sums but I am not too sure. Can someone give me insight on how to start?

Comment: @NiklasB. Could you expand on how this is done?

Comment: You fix the left boundary. Then you increase the right boundary one by one, keeping track of the number of occurences of each number (you don't even need prefix sums). You can check in O(1) whether the interval is balanced by using hash maps to associate elements with how often they occur in the interval and additional multiset of numbers of occurences.

Comment: How would you use the hash map to do this?

Comment: It maintains the assocation element -> number of occurences in the interval.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in O(n) or O(nlogn)?

Comment: Why must you use a hash map to keep  track of number of occurrences? Couldn't you just use an array? And for checking if it is balanced using hash map do you just use .count() for each of the elements?

Comment: No, you can't use an array if your numbers are unbounded (I don't know if they are). However you can use coordinate compression and arrays in that case, yes. And no, you can't use count for each element, otherwise you don't get O(n^2). You need to keep the counts in a separate data structure that lets you check whether all its elements are equal in O(1) (for example, again a multiset implemented as a hash table)

Comment: But a hashmap doesn't have a function that checks whether all its elements are equal? It only has a .count() for a given key.

Comment: As I said, you would need a *second* data structure. For example keep a hashmap of number of occurences: 1 -> 2, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 2. Keep an additional multiset that only manages the set of values (`{2, 3, 2}` in this case).

Comment: What do you do after that?

Comment: Hah? This allows you to check whether an interval is balanced is O(1). Just check whether the multiset contains only one distinct value.

Comment: But to check whether the multiset contains only one distinct value don't you need to iterate over the elements of the multiset?

Comment: No. You just need to count the number of different values. For example if you use `unordered_map<int,int>` in C++, you just check whether `.size() == 1`.

Comment: Wait... but won't a multiset of {2,2,2} for example have a size of 3?

Comment: Yep, I edited. You would use a map number -> cardinality. So `{2,2,2}` would be `2 -> 3` and have size 1

Comment: So for example, we would have `unordered_map<int,int> num_to_occ, occ_to_count; void insert(int x) { occ_to_count[num_to_occ[x]]--; num_to_occ[x]++; occ_to_count[num_to_occ[x]]++; }` and `bool isbalanced() { return occ_to_count.size() == 1; }`. `remove` would be analogous to `insert`

Comment: loop from 0 to n-1, counting the number of elements into a map. Then loop from n-1 to 0, subtracting 1 from the respective count for the element at that index, breaking from the loop at the first instance when all counts are the same....

Comment: @NiklasB. So after you finish changing all the right boundaries you increment the left boundary then repeat it right? For this you also need to clear the unordered_map? How would you do that?

Comment: @NicholasHamilton I'm not sure if that works. Could you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: @user2612743 Yes exactly. Clearing is easy, even if it's O(n) you can amortize the cost. Your programming language should handle that for you (in C++ it's `.clear()`)

Comment: @NicholasHamilton I don't understand that at all. Won't you just consider prefixes that way?

Comment: @NiklasB. I am trying to use the insert and isbalanced() functions but it doesn't seem to be working. After doing `insert(1);
    insert(2);
    insert(1);
    insert(2);
` and calling `isbalanced()` it return false.

Comment: @user2612743 Well yeah. Don't consider count 0. You could try doing some debugging and printing out data structures to find bugs like these

Comment: @NiklasB. What do you mean by "don't consider count 0"?

Comment: @user2612743 Sorry pal you'll have to do some of the work on your own. It's an easy to find problem. Hint: print the contents of `occ_to_count` after the first insert

Comment: I get -1 when I do that because it was originally zero.

Comment: @NiklasB. I don't quite get how the unordered map stuff works. In the example of inserting 1,2,1,2, won't the size of occ_to_count be 3? Why are you checking to see if size==1 in isbalanced()? And why do you subtract 1 from the occ_to_count?

Comment: occ_to_count is the multiset of values of the map number_to_occ. After inserting 1,2,1,2 we have number_to_occ = 1->2, 2->2, so occ_to_count  = 2 -> 2 (because we have two numbers with count 2). We have to ignore the zeroes.

Comment: if it is a multiset then why is it declared as an unordered_map? Shoudln't the build in multiset<> class in c++ be used?

Comment: See python code in my answer.

Comment: @user2612743 Yes, we could use unordered_multiset too. But it's slightly easier to figure out if there is only one different value with a `map`. In general a multiset does not allow us to figure out the number of different values efficiently

Comment: @NiklasB. Why do you subtract one from occ_to_count every time you insert? Shouldn't you remove the old value of occ_to_count instead?

Comment: Removing a value of the multiset corresponds to decrementing its associated counter. Man you ask a lot of questions instead of thinking about it on your own (which you might learn a lot more from)

Comment: Sorry about the questions, I'm sort of new to algorithms and such :(. I don't see how decrementing the counter removes it from the multiset. Don't you need to use .erase() for that? Won't simply decrementing the counter still leave it in the set and contribute to its size?

Comment: Yep, that's the bug we talked about earlier. We don't care about zero keys or zero values in the map `occ_to_count`, so we need some additional logic to erase zeroes.

Comment: Doesn't decrementing also lead to negative value? Because at first all values are unitialized so when you go to decrement won't you get -1?

Comment: Yes, negative values are also bad. But that can only happen for key zero, which you canjust ignore

Comment: What is more important? the length of the interval or the number of elements?

Comment: Your problem statement says "I want to find the longest subinterval that results in an equal number of each elements". If you are looking for EACH element you should also include 4. Just pointing out statement is not very clear although input/output clears all doubts.

Comment: Also, with DP solution to this problem will go O(n2) and extra spaces (~O(n2)).

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#The demo data
SET = [1,1,2,3,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1]

#Function to map the counts of the values in the set
def map(x):
        ret = {}
        for v in x:
                if v not in ret.keys():
                        ret.update({v:0})
                ret[v] += 1
        return ret

#Function to check if all counts in the map are the same
def checkMap(x):
        val = None
        for k,v in x.items():
                if val != None and v != val:
                        return False
                else:
                        val=v
        return True

#Determine the initial counts
counts = map(SET)

#Now step back from end index to start
for ix in range(len(SET) - 1, 0, -1):
        val = SET[ix]
        counts[val] += -1
        if counts[val] == 0:
                del counts[val]
        if checkMap(counts):
                print "Condition Reached, Largest Subset is:",SET[0:ix]
                break
```

Comment: Who says the optimal subinterval is a prefix of the map? Also this isn't a very optimal solution complexity-wise. It's O(n^2), but we already know an O(n^2) solution for OPs problem

Comment: Try `A = [1,1,2,3,4,5,...,n+1]` and assume that `k=1` is always the last number checked in the loop in `checkMap` (in general even assuming good hashing it is expected to be the k/2th number being checked if there are k numbers in `x`). Thus `checkMap` is linear in the prefix size. So the total runtime is O(1 + 2 + ... + n) = O(n^2)