# Determining the Longest Continguous Subsequence

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, dynamic-programming, greedy

There are N nodes (1 <= N <= 100,000) various positions along a
long one-dimensional length.  The ith node is at position x_i (an
integer in the range 0...1,000,000,000) and has a node type b_i(an integer in
the range 1..8). Nodes can not be in the same position

You want to get a range on this one-dimension in which all of the types of nodes are fairly represented. Therefore, you want to ensure that, for whatever types of nodes that are present in the range, there is an equal number of each node type (for example, a range with 27 each of types 1 and 3 is ok, a range with 27 of types 1, 3, and 4 is
ok, but 9 of type 1 and 10 of type 3 is not ok). You also want
at least K (K >= 2) types (out of the 8 total) to be represented in the
rand. Find the maximum size of this range that satisfies the constraints.  The size of a photo is the difference between the maximum and minimum positions of the nodes in the photo.

If there are no ranges satisfying the constraints, output -1 instead.

```
INPUT:

* Line 1: N and K separated by a space

* Lines 2..N+1: Each line contains a description of a node as two
        integers separated by a space; x(i) and its node type.

INPUT:

9 2  
1 1  
5 1  
6 1  
9 1  
100 1  
2 2  
7 2  
3 3  
8 3     

INPUT DETAILS:  
Node types: 1 2 3 - 1 1 2 3 1  - ...  -   1  
  Locations: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... 99 100

OUTPUT:

* Line 1: A single integer indicating the maximum size of a fair
       range. If no such range exists, output -1.

OUTPUT:

6

OUTPUT DETAILS:

The range from x = 2 to x = 8 has 2 each of types 1, 2, and 3. The range
from x = 9 to x = 100 has 2 of type 1, but this is invalid because K = 2
and so you need at least 2 distinct types of nodes.
```

Could You Please help in suggesting some algorithm to solve this. I have thought about using some sort of priority queue or stack data structure, but am really unsure how to proceed.

Thanks, Todd

Comment: This is essentially equivalent to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901113/algorithm-that-balances-the-number-of-elements-in-a-subinterval-of-an-array

Answer (score 0):

It's not too difficult to invent almost linear-time algorithm because recently similar problem was discussed on CodeChef: ["ABC-Strings"](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/40359/abcstr-editorial).

1. Sort nodes by their positions.
2. Prepare all possible subsets of node types (for example, we could expect types 1,2,4,5,7 to be present in resulting interval and all other types not present there). For K=2 there may be only 256-8-1=247 subsets. For each subset perform remaining steps:
3. Initialize 8 type counters to [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0].
4. For each node perform remaining steps:
5. Increment counter for current node type.
6. Take `L` counters for types included to current subset, subtract first of them from other `L-1` counters, which produces `L-1` values. Take remaining `8-L` counters and combine them together with those `L-1` values into a tuple of 7 values.
7. Use this tuple as a key for hash map. If hash map contains no value for this key, add a new entry with this key and value equal to the position of current node. Otherwise subtract value in the hash map from the position of current node and (possibly) update the best result.